# why is a1/a2 = b1/b2 = c1/c2 is said to be dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

in linear equation in two variable there are some identities that tells us weather the pair of linear equations have no-solution, unique solution or a infinitely many solution...

like wise unique and infinitely many solution are called consistent and in consistent infinitely many solutions are called dependent

i.e

```
    a1     b1     c1
   ---- = ---- = ----  is called dependent   
    a2     b2     c2
```

---

### Question

why it is called so?

i mean on what thing is this solution depends upon for which it is said to be dependent?

thanks!

Comment: If $a_1/a_2=b_1/b_2=c_1/c_2=Q$, then the vectors $u=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $v=(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ are said to be *linearly dependent*, which means $u-Qv=(0,0,0)$, what's called a "linear dependence relation". Maybe that's what you are running into?